# How do I read/edit a .xuk file extension?

Tags: disassembly, windows, file-format

I am trying to reverse engineer a license key for some software, the company that made it went out of business. In doing so, if you didn't already have the key their $50,000 machines become paperweights.

The key to unlock their driver takes information and exports it, then you send it to the company which they send back a different `.xuk` file which you import and it unlocks the driver.

I have both the before and after `.xuk` files and can open them in a hex editor, but I don't know how to read it.

Comment: What is the size of .xuf file, is it compressed etc. Please provide some more details about file.

Comment: Understanding a file format just by looking at a few sample files is next to impossible unless you exactly know what is stored in that files or the file structure is pretty simple. This is equivalent to learning a language by just looking at some pages from a book with unknown content. A more realistic way is to disassemble the program theat reads and processes those files. Even if this code is obfuscated and equipped with anti-reverseengineering techniques it will be much more simple to reverse the code than just the files.

Comment: Any more details on the machines, the stack, company, driver or link the actual files?